# Moving elements in HTML emails

Tags: html, css

I currently have this layout for a HTML email I am creating:

[image]

I am trying to move the text so that it starts from the start of the image (essentially, move the text up) and then, create a gap of around 10px between the text and the red download button.

The issue is I'm struggling to address this using `tables` which are essential for HTML emails.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#0066cb">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td height="240" width="15"><!-- PADDING (CREATING AREA) --></td>
                 <td>
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td height="10"><!-- PADDING --></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>
                      <!-- IMAGE  -->
                                                                   <img src="images/unnamed (4).png"height="250"  style="display:block;" border="0" />
                     </td>
                     <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:27px;line-height:35px;color:#ffffff;">
                      eguide title lorum ipsum <br>
                      dolor sit amet labore et
                      <img src="images/unnamed (5).png" alt="test"   style="display:block;" border="0" />
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>             
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7bzgpd02/

Comment: please create snippet for demo

Comment: You should upload your image as url in the example. So that we can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Added this code to your inline style on the table field containing the "eguide" text (tables usually default to vertically centered until directed otherwise):

```
vertical-align: top;
```

See the below example, it now works:

```css
* {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#0066cb">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td height="240" width="15"><!-- PADDING (CREATING AREA) --></td>
                 <td>
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td height="10"><!-- PADDING --></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>
                      <!-- IMAGE  -->
                                                                   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Xenith" height="250"  style="display:block;" border="0" />
                     </td>
                     <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:27px;line-height:35px;color:#ffffff; vertical-align: top;">eguide title lorum ipsum <br>
                      dolor sit amet labore et
                      <img src="images/unnamed (5).png" alt="test"   style="display:block;" border="0" />
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>             
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel for your suggestion. I can see the change you're suggesting work when I run the code snippet. However, when applying the changes to my code, it moves the text above the image. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/7bzgpd02/

Comment: That's because your image has space above it. See here: http://i65.tinypic.com/2z3tc0w.png. Remove the background and all space around the graphic and add the colour back in the table cell instead.